# How to add a hyphen instead of slash in rewrite_rules_array wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

hi i want hyphen to be added as string while rewriting WordPress URLs. this is my code

```
$phyphen=htmlentities($phyphen);
$str='([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)'.$phyphen.'([^/]+)';

$aNewRules['ad/'.$str.'/?$'] = 'index.php?property=$matches[6]&sale_type=$matches[1]&property_type=$matches[2]&property_state=$matches[3]&property_city=$matches[4]&property_id=$matches[5]';
```

Here i want to add add a hyphen(-) in place on `$phyphen` but it doesn't work and lead to 404 but if a use underscore or slash in place of `$phyphen` it works fine

is there any way to add hyphen in URL instead of slash at a particular point